# ASP.NET get twitter RSS screen name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if it is possible to cut off screen name from twitter RSS
the current format is like this

```
<item>
    <title>USERNAME: blahblahblah </title>
    <description>USERNAME: blahblahbla x5 blahblahbla x10 blahblahbla x15</description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 20 Jan 2012 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
    <guid>http://twitter.com/USERNAME/blahblahbla </guid>
    <link>http://twitter.com/USERNAME/blahblahbla </link>
    <twitter:source>please ignore here :-) </twitter:source>
    <twitter:place/>
 </item>
```

Any way to just get the USERNAME, for example from the "description" tag, get the text (USERNAME) before the colon?

I am really new to ASP.NET, grateful for a bit detailed information

Many thanks

Comment: what is the input here?  are you starting from a raw XML string? is it part of a serialized object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath expression should get you want you want:

```
<%#XPath("substring-before(description, \":\")")%>
```

Here I assume that the XMLDatasource looks like:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource
     runat="server"
     ID="XmlDataSource1"
     XPath="item" 
     DataFile="myfile.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
string InnerText = "USERNAME: blahblahblah";

Match match = Regex.Match(InnerText, "^(.*):");
string username;
if (match.Success)
{
    username = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```